# Properties undefined on getInitialState

Tags: reactjs

React noob here, trying to set an initial value for my checkbox control. I set the property and am trying to set the state to the property value using the getInitialState. Problem is, the props seem to be undefined in the getInitialState. I've simplified and created a jsbin to show the issue.https://jsbin.com/cujeveh/edit?html,js,console,output

```
var testcontrol = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function () {
        return { testval: this.props.testval };
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
        <input type="checkbox" checked={this.state.testval?"checked":""}}/>
        );
    }
});
React.render(
    <Container lblOn="yup" lblOff="nope"
       buttonText="saveit" testval="1" />, document.body);
```

Also within the jsbin, tried the componentDidMount method with the same result. If I update the getInitialState to replace the prop with a hardcoded value, everything works fine. I did read the React docs [here](https://facebook.github.io/react/tips/props-in-getInitialState-as-anti-pattern.html) and did see the antipattern statement but am only trying to set the initial state which I understood as okay.

Comment: Is there a specific reason you're trying to set a prop as a state in this situation?

Comment: Let's say that I have a form that someone has filled out before. I want to display the previous values on that form so I can update the values. I can't seem to find any other way to get the data to be changed into the control. Every sample that I've come across starts the form from a blank state. I need to pre-populate the form with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, you're setting `testval` prop on the `<Container>` component, but not on the `<Chkbox1>` component, which is the component that is checking for it. Probably a minor oversight. You just need to change:

```
<Chkbox1 ref="box1" lblOn={this.props.lblOn} 
         lblOff={this.props.lblOff} />
```

to

```
<Chkbox1 ref="box1" lblOn={this.props.lblOn} 
         lblOff={this.props.lblOff} testval={this.props.testval}/>
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution Rossipedia.